# XQuery UNION of multiple criteria

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

How do you code in XQuery (SQL Server 2012) to do an `.exist` with multiple criteria?

```
Declare @x xml = '
    <row ParentID="45" ObjectID="0" Node="root.local.navigation[7]" itemKey="page" itemValue="Confirmation" itemType="string" />
    <row ParentID="45" ObjectID="0" Node="root.local.navigation[7]" itemKey="visited" itemValue="false" itemType="bool" />'

-- These work fine
SELECT @x.exist('/row[@Node eq "root.local.navigation[7]"]')
SELECT @x.exist('/row[@itemValue eq "Confirmation"]')
```

But when I run the below it returns error

> XQuery [exist()]: The XQuery syntax 'union' is not supported.

```
SELECT @x.exist('/row[@Node eq "root.local.navigation[7]"] | /row[@itemValue eq "Confirmation"]')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `or` should work just fine as it does the same thing.

```
SELECT @x.exist('/row[@Node eq "root.local.navigation[7]" or @itemValue eq "Confirmation"]')
```

Comment: Works when I change the or to and.  Thanks

Comment: Follow-on question posted here -->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177956/xquery-retrieval-of-a-value

Comment: If you use an `and` and you get your desired output you weren't looking for a union operator in the first place...

Comment: Correct, I somewhat mis-stated my requirements, and your comment got me to where I can pick it up and finish.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Using `/row[... or ...]` is the solution to the problem as you described it.  You mentioned that you get the desired result with `/row[... and ...]`.  In that case, you can also use the following, which applies several filters in a row, each constructing a narrower sequence:

`/row[...][...]`